# Upper and lower controls on chart

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Trying to create a chart with upper and lower control limits.  I was trying to achieve a similar look to the 1st and 2nd image, where the upper and lower controls are a block rather than my effort, image 3, where I've just made a thick line. Any ideas?

Many Thanks

Design View

[image]

Report Executed
[image]

My Version
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property you're looking for is **StripLines**.

With the Properties Window open (F4) select the vertical axis of your chart, and go to the `StripLines` property. In the window that appears, add a new member and enter the following for your upper control:

- `BackgroundColor`: Pink
- `IntervalOffset`: 80
- `StripWidth`: 20

You can also adjust the title text as necessary, and add another member with similar properties for your lower and middle controls.